# Understanding MIPS Code

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science, mars-simulator

I have the following code to understand, from an exam:

```
.data
msg1: .asciiz "0x616263"
msg2: .word 0x636261
#msg2: .byte 0x61,0x62,0x63

.text 
main:   
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg1
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg2
    syscall
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

The proccessor according to the exam works in Little Endian method.

The output of this code, according to the exam is:

```
abc616263
```

My output on MARS 4.4 simulator was 0x616263abc.

1. I guess the difference in the anwers comes from Little Endian vs. Big Endian methods?
2. Why is the output of msg2 is abc? I don't understand why from 0x636261 input, I get "abc" output?
   I guess this is due to the fact that this is stored within a word?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. Whoever told you that the output should be `abc616263` is wrong. The code clearly prints the string `"0x616263"` first, so `0x616263abc` is the expected output.
2. On a little-endian system the 32-bit word `0x636261` is the same as if you had the four bytes `0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x00` (the `0x00` is there because a word is four bytes, and the most significant byte of `0x636261` is 0). If we view that as ASCII we have `'a', 'b', 'c', NUL`, which equals the NUL-terminated string `"abc"`.